# How do I add attributes to a single menu's links?

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I want to add some BEM classes to a single menu's links. I cannot find a way to do this in Drupal's GUI so I assume this must be done programmatically.

How would you go about this exactly? I've no idea what file any function would even go on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the [Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module.  This looks like it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For drupal 8 try [Menu Link Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes) or [Link Attributes widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_attributes)